# Vertical Layout not working properly when children are instantiated - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layout, instantiation, vertical-scrolling

I have a GameObject with a vertical layout component, and when I instantiate its children for content, the children overlap with each other which means it does not follow the vertical layout order and just on top of each other (see the photo below).

[The GameObject (parent)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjhwY.png)

The child (ArticleCard) that I instantiate or cloned also has a vertical layout because I wanted it to have a responsive height depending on the length of its children's texts. You can see it in the editor of the second photo.

[The ArticleCard (clone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axN7B.png)

Both the parent and the child that I instantiate or clone have vertical layout and content size fitter set to `Min Size.` The rest of the information about their inspector is in the two previous photos for reference.

But when I changed or tweaked just a single component like the padding in the vertical layout or anything in their inspector or re-arranged them in the hierarchy, even though I changed it back, the vertical layout suddenly worked just fine and removed the bug.

When the `GameObjects` are just instantiated, the vertical layout will not work, but when I edit or change just a single component, it will snap to how it is supposed to be. In this third photo, I unchecked and checked the `Child Force Expand` `height` value in the Vertical Layout Group, which snaps to how it is supposed to be.

[ArticleCard (Clone)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cglHY.png)

This is the script for Instantiating the ArticleCard object, in the final if statement which checks if the name of the GameObject is "FireFacts".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TryInstantiate : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject articleTemplate, MG_ArticleTemplate, divider, objTxt, tipTxt, g;

    [SerializeField] private GameData gameData;
    //private string[] articleSplit;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        
        if (gameObject.name == "Articles")
        {
            articleTemplate = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;

            if (!(gameData.articlesList == null))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gameData.articlesList.Count; i++)
                {
                    //articleSplit = gameData.articlesList[i].Split("#");
                    g = Instantiate(articleTemplate, transform);
                    g.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = gameData.getArticle(gameData.articlesList[i]).title;
                    g.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Published by " +
                        gameData.getPublisherDetail(gameData.articlesList[i]).type + " on " +
                        gameData.getArticle(gameData.articlesList[i]).date;
                    g.SetActive(true);
                }
            }
            // Destroy(articleTemplate);
            articleTemplate.SetActive(false);

        }
        else if (gameObject.name == "Objectives")
        {

            divider = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            objTxt = transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;

            if (!(gameData.objectivesList == null))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gameData.objectivesList.Count; i++)
                {
                    g = Instantiate(objTxt, transform);
                    g.transform.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = gameData.objectivesList[i];
                    g.SetActive(true);
                    g = Instantiate(divider, transform);
                    g.SetActive(true);
                }
            }

            // Destroy(objTxt);
            // Destroy(divider);

            objTxt.SetActive(false);
            //divider.SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (gameObject.name == "Clues")
        {

            divider = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            tipTxt = transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;

            if (!(gameData.cluesList == null))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gameData.cluesList.Count; i++)
                {
                    g = Instantiate(tipTxt, transform);
                    g.transform.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = gameData.cluesList[i];
                    g.SetActive(true);
                    g = Instantiate(divider, transform);
                    g.SetActive(true);
                }
            }

            tipTxt.SetActive(false);
            //divider.SetActive(false);
        }else if(gameObject.name == "FireFacts")
        {
            MG_ArticleTemplate = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
            //Debug.Log()
            if (!(gameData.mgArticlesList == null))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gameData.mgArticlesList.Count; i++)
                {
                    g = Instantiate(MG_ArticleTemplate, transform);
                    g.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = gameData.getMG_Article(gameData.mgArticlesList[i]).title;
                    g.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Published by <link=publisher><color=blue><u><b><font=\"Fredoka-Bold SDF\">" +
                        gameData.getMG_Publisher(gameData.mgArticlesList[i]).name + "</font></b></u></color></link> on <font=\"Fredoka-Bold SDF\">" +
                        gameData.getMG_Article(gameData.mgArticlesList[i]).date + "</font>";
                    g.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = gameData.getMG_Article(gameData.mgArticlesList[i]).description;
                    g.SetActive(true);
                }

                transform.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().padding.top = 15;
                transform.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().spacing = 15;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        foreach (Transform clone in gameObject.transform)
        {
            if (clone.name == "ArticleCard(Clone)" || clone.name == "ObjectiveText(Clone)" || clone.name == "CluesText(Clone)" || clone.name == "Divider(Clone)")
            {
                Destroy(clone.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give to specify the Layers, don't give all the Layouts the default Layer UI

Comment: @Yugerten I added a new Layer and set it to `ArticleCard` gameobject, the object that I instantiate as you can see in the photos, but the problem is still there. I think the problem is in the Vertical Layout itself or somewhere. I just don't know what it is.

Comment: @Yugerten what does the Layer will do specifically?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using Coroutines. The problem is fixed, or the layout is fixed every time I tweak or edit anything at runtime. I turned a layout off and then on via script, but it did not work. This is because the code for enabling and disabling the component happens within a frame, even though it works when I disable and enable it at runtime. This is because it happens with a frame delay, so it works when doing it at runtime. So I created a coroutine to re-enable the Vertical Layout component within 0.001 seconds; with this time frame, it will not be noticeable that it has a delay.

```
    if(gameObject.name == "FireFacts")
    {
        transform.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().enabled = false;
        MG_ArticleTemplate = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
        if (!(gameData.mgArticlesList == null))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < gameData.mgArticlesList.Count; i++)
            {
                g = Instantiate(MG_ArticleTemplate, transform);
                g.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = gameData.getMG_Article(gameData.mgArticlesList[i]).title;
                g.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "Published by <link=publisher><color=blue><u><b><font=\"Fredoka-Bold SDF\">" +
                    gameData.getMG_Publisher(gameData.mgArticlesList[i]).name + "</font></b></u></color></link> on <font=\"Fredoka-Bold SDF\">" +
                    gameData.getMG_Article(gameData.mgArticlesList[i]).date + "</font>";
                g.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = gameData.getMG_Article(gameData.mgArticlesList[i]).description;
                g.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
        StartCoroutine(refresh());
    }


    private IEnumerator refresh()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f);
        transform.GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>().enabled = true;
    }
```